# DBMS_LOB.APPEND File is getting cut because of concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below block. I want to replace that concatenation and also have a records from the cursor in new line.

For small data set it works,but when the number of rows returned by the cursor is 600+ it cuts the file. I think its because of conversion of CLOB to Varchar2 when || is used.

How do I resolve it?

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT  ID, CA_ID, STATUS,S_DATE, E_DATE FROM TEST; -- Here I have a big query
    v_MESG                  CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
    v_Interim               CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
    v_col                   VARCHAR2(500);
    CRLF                    VARCHAR2(2) := CHR(13)||CHR(10);
    v_fileHandler           UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    v_col:= '"ID","CA_ID","Status","S_Date","E_Date"'||CRLF;

    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_MESG, TRUE);

    FOR v_cur IN cur LOOP
        BEGIN
        v_Interim := NULL;
        v_Interim:= v_col||v_cur.ID||',"'||
                    v_cur.CA_ID||'","'||
                    v_cur.Status||'","'||
                    v_cur.S_Date||'","'||
                    v_cur.E_DATE||'"'||CRLF
            ;
        DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_mesg, v_Interim); 
        v_col := NULL;
        END;
    END LOOP;
     v_fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('XML_PROCESS_TEST',v_file_name , 'w');
         UTL_FILE.PUT(v_fileHandler, v_MESG);
         UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_fileHandler);
END;
```

Comment: Why are you creating the temporary lob in the first place?  You're already generating one line of data at a time.  Why not `utl_file.put_line` each line as you assemble it rather than storing everything in memory and then dumping it to disk?  If you did want to store the data in memory as a first step, you'd generally want to read one line of data from the `clob` at a time in a loop and write that to disk.

Comment: @justin-cave Let me try utl_file.put_line, will let you know Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: @justin It worked!! Thanks a lot Justin I used utl_file.put_line. Appreciate your quick reply Thanks again.